# require.resolve problem on Linux/gitlab Error: You attempted to import /a/b/node_modules/*/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, npm, webpack

I've been struggling with this all day:
I have a React project, and am using **react-app-rewired** to add stuff like *"https", "stream", "crypto"*, etc.

Unfortunately, using "**require.resolve('*ANYTHING*')**", in the '[config-overrides.js](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)' results in an **ERROR** when the project is pushed to build via the Gitlab CI (which is running some sort of linux as far as I'm aware)

The error: (when running npm build on Windows - it works, it fails on the CI)

```
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /builds/Team/Project-name/node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

I've also tried using the [NodePolyfillPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin), but the problem persists. E.g. its a **require.resolve** issue.